# Python Pandas: Mean every n rows in a new column repeated n times

Tags: python, pandas, mean, repeat

I want to take the mean of column `c2` every three rows and save the results in a new column `c3` such that each mean is repeated three times. This code can do the job:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': ['A', 'B','C','D','E','F'], 'c2': [1, 2, 3,3,4,5]})
nrow=3
temp=df['c2'].rolling(nrow).mean()      #Take rolling mean
temp= temp[nrow-1::nrow]                #Select mean value every 3 rows
temp=temp.loc[temp.index.repeat(nrow)]  #Repeat each mean value 3 times
temp.index = range(0,len(df))           #Fix index 
df['c3']=temp
print(df)
```

the results should be column `c3` with [2,2,2,4,4,4]. Is there an easier way than this 5 lines of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with integer division by index or helper array by length of `DataFrame`:

```
nrow = 3

#if default RangeIndex
df['c3'] = df.groupby(df.index // nrow)['c2'].transform('mean')

#alternative if not default RangeIndex
#df['c3'] = df.groupby(np.arange(df) // nrow)['c2'].transform('mean')
print(df)

  c1  c2  c3
0  A   1   2
1  B   2   2
2  C   3   2
3  D   3   4
4  E   4   4
5  F   5   4
```